# Render Action button

Tags: acumatica

I was creating a new Screen with the FormDetail template where I would be having a Filter DAC and list of DAC to display on Grid. I created the page successfully. Then,I wanted to put a button on the top of the button which would pull data from api and refresh grid. So, I wrote the below code to render an action button on page(FormDetail) like this. 
[image]
But, it is not working.

```
    using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace AcumaticaSquarePOSIntegration
{
  public class SquarePOSTransactionInquiry : PXGraph<SquarePOSTransactionInquiry>
  {

    public PXSave<MasterTable> Save;
    public PXCancel<MasterTable> Cancel;


    public PXFilter<MasterTable> MasterView;
    public PXFilter<DetailsTable> DetailsView;

    public PXAction<MasterTable> Calc;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Calc")]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable calc(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      return adapter.Get();
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
    {

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DetailsTable : IBqlTable
    {

    }


  }

      }
```

I even tried add

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have two PXFilters, change the second to PxSelect and make the PXFilter your first Data view in the list.

Comment: I forgot to change that part. But, even chaning DetailsView to PXSelect doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using PXProcessButton instead of PXButton.
Also make sure MasterView is specified in aspx as a PrimaryView.

Comment: Still no luck. This is the changed code.
`public PXAction<DetailsTable> calc;
    
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Calc")]
    [PXProcessButton]
    protected virtual void Calc(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
      
    }`
Primary view is the the MasterView.
http://www.screencast.com/t/bMLf5f4H

Comment: As primary view is MasterView - you should specify PXAction<MasterTable> (Not PXAction<DetailsTable> as now).

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. Thank you. :)